# WiMax Ad-Hoc Network

Tags: wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, wimax

Is there a way I can connect 2 computers via WiMAX without using 4G networks or any other service?

I know WiFi network adapters can be used this way, so I wondered why can't WiMAX be the same..

I need to stream HD video from one PC to another 300 meters apart. But no line of sight...

What hardware do I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

While in theory you could do this with any sort of radio with the correct software, practically speaking that's not going to exist for these.  WiMax radios are designed to communicate with the broadcast towers only.

(If you need to stream HD video in real-time over a distance that short, a wired network is best if at all possible.)

Comment: for 300 meters I would recommend a minimum of at least 2 repeaters also if you plan to use cat5 or cat6.

Comment: Yeah, @EBGreen is right - that's too far for a straight CAT5/6 run.

Comment: Thank you but there is no way i can wire them.. i know that you can buy pc network cards that work with wimax freq, but i dont know if you could connect two of this ad-hoc..

Comment: As I said, it's only designed to communicate with the towers.  This is almost exactly equivalent to asking if you can use a 3G cellular radio in a computer to do the same thing, if that helps.

Comment: There are ways to 'beam' wifi, by focusing the beam. This known as highly directional antennas. Looks for a 'Grid Antenna' type. If you want to become crazzzzy you can also look for 'Dish Antenna' type of antennas. But again, maybe grid antenna is what you are looking for?